# Entity Framework Migrations with Multiple Web Config Transforms

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have created an ASP.NET MVC 4 project in Visual Studio 2010 using Entity Framework 5 with migrations enabled. I have multiple web config files for different environments (Debug, Staging, Release) which will specify different database connectionStrings depending on the environment. How do I handle migrations using the `Update-Database` command from the Package Manager Console with the multiple config files? Each time I run this command, it defaults to the main Web.config connection string. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: how are you deploying your code to the various environments? ie. using Visual Studio? CI Jenkins?

Comment: I'm currently using the publish web option in Visual Studio.

Comment: I thought there is an option to update database

Comment: I just answered a similar question. Hope it is useful:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/22189549/2179408

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to try and keep things as simple as possible, the way I worked around running migrations on my remote staging and production servers, is to run the following command from the package console (data source and user/pass would change depending on which server I wanted to run the migrations against):

```
Update-Database -Verbose -ConnectionString "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=db;User Id=user;Password=pass;" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
```

This has worked for me so far in case anyone else is looking. Thanks everyone for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

To migrate to different envrionment, you should use [Web config transform tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), I don't think it's the responsibility of Entity Framework Migrations.

Comment: The transforms are working properly. I'm unclear of how to handle migrations and updating the database in the different environments.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx

EF Code First Migrations comes with a migrate tool which allows you to run the 'update' commands via command prompt.

I'm not really sure how your set up, but we did something similar where we deploy code through our CI server (Jenkins). 
I then added a post deployment step to run the update-database via command line.

What's great about it is you can specify connection strings too.

Again, it all depends how this fits into your process, you could even use Nant to execute this for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This migrate.exe tool might be what I'm looking for.

A side question I have for you related to your deployment process, is how do you revert back if the migration fails, or something goes unexpected?

Comment: We would roll-back the tradional way. DBMigrations allows you to target a migration script (if you need to roll back) but I would not rely on this for rolling back your production servers. You can also generate a script from migrations