# Access the database name inside Up in DbMigration

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following code in a code-first migration:

```
public partial class RunSQLInit : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        this.Sql(SqlFiles.Create_Job_ClearExpiredData);
    }

    [...]
}
```

where `SqlFiles.Create_Job_ClearExpiredData` is a resx-file returning an SQL-file as a string. The SQL creates and schedules a Server Agent job in SQL Server.

Now, the SQL have two "variables" I need the ability to change before running the migration on a database: the name of the database the job should run on, and the name for the actual job. That would be fine if I had one environment only, but I deploy this code-first project to a number of environments, who differ in database names and also in what I should call the Job.

I see three possibilities:

1. Get hold of the connection string currently being used inside the Up()-method, and use that to parse out the database name and do a replace for it to the SQL-string before running it. But how would I go about getting the "connection string currently being used"?
2. Somehow pass a variable to the migrations when running `Update-Database` in the Package Manager Console, which could be accessible inside the migrations. How would I go about that?
3. Use another solution for creating the Job. We rely heavily on the ease of deploying from the code-first models to all environments, so it should be easily automated somehow without additional labour when updating databases, and producing deployment scripts (with `Update-Database -script`)

A small cut out from the SQL-script in question is this:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Run SP', 
    @step_id=1,
    @subsystem=N'TSQL',
    @command=N'exec sp_ClearExpiredData;', 
    @database_name=@databaseName, --This is where I need the varying database name!
    @flags=0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to my problem was to simply use this inside the SQL-file:

```
set @databaseName = db_name()
```

Since the current context is already the database I will use for the job, it's already there. Too easy.

Answer (score 4):

I had to declare my @DBName variable in order to set it. Error otherwise:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@DBName".

Complete code:

```
Sql("DECLARE @DBName nvarchar(50), @SQLString nvarchar(200)\r\n" +
    "SET @DBName = db_name();\r\n" +
    "SET @SQLString = \'ALTER DATABASE [\' + @DBName + \'] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS\'\r\n" +
    "EXEC( @SQLString )", suppressTransaction: true);
```

Answer (score 3):

The question is old and since then Entity Framework has been changed a lot (Core) but in any case I would like to post some solution which can be very useful in some situations (EF Core). So in this case you simply replace the `[DatabaseNameToReplace]` with your current db name.

Create a new class `CustomMigrationsSqlGenerator`:

```cs
public class CustomMigrationsSqlGenerator : SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator
{
    public CustomMigrationsSqlGenerator(
        MigrationsSqlGeneratorDependencies dependencies,
        IRelationalAnnotationProvider migrationsAnnotations)
        : base(dependencies, migrationsAnnotations)
    {
    }

    protected override void Generate(
        MigrationOperation operation,
        IModel model,
        MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
    {
        if (operation is SqlOperation sqlOperation)
        {
            var dbName = this.Dependencies.CurrentContext.Context.Database.GetDbConnection().Database;
            sqlOperation.Sql = sqlOperation.Sql.Replace("[DatabaseNameToReplace]", $"[{dbName}]");
        }

        base.Generate(operation, model, builder);
    }
}
```

Register that class with your dbcontext:

```cs
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<IMigrationsSqlGenerator, CustomMigrationsSqlGenerator>();
    }
}
```

And then all your plain sql migrations could look like this:

```cs
[DbContext(typeof(MyDbContext))]
[Migration("20221223000000_Task1234_AddFileGroup")]
public class M20221223000000_Task1234_AddFileGroup : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.Sql("ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseNameToReplace] ADD FILEGROUP MyFilegroupName");
    }
}
```

I hope it's helpful.

For more information please follow the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/operations

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is good for your database name. See [Is there any connection string parser in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4804099/150342)

The Job probably needs to come from the config file. Put the name in AppSettings then you can do

`string jobName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["jobName"]`

You could do the same for dbName too of course:

`string dbName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbName"]`

I have a config class that looks like this:

```
public class Config
{
    public static string ConnectionStringName
    {
        get { return GetValue("ConnectionStringName", "SID_2013Context"); }
    }    

    private static string GetValue(string key, string defaultValue)
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] ?? defaultValue;
    }
}
```

My DBContext class constructor looks like this:

```
    public SID2013Context()
        : base("Name=" + Config.ConnectionStringName)
    {
    }
```

My web.config has a connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SID_2013Context" connectionString="etc" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

So I could add a couple of properties to my config class:

```
public static string ConnectionString
{
    get { return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ConnectionStringName]
                                     .ConnectionString; }
}

public static string DatabaseName
{
    get
    {
        var builder = new System.Data.SqlClient
                      .SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConnectionString);
        return builder.DataSource;
    }
}
```

Then in my Up() migration:

```
   public override void Up()
   {
         string databaseName = Config.DatabaseName;
   }
```

Comment: The problem is that I need the names to change, depending on what database I deploy to. An AppSetting would set the name for the whole app, regardless of what I deploy it to.

Comment: Option 1 does not work, as I cannot access the "current running" connection string in the Up-method. That is my problem.

Comment: It is normal for the ConnectionString and AppSettings to change from environment to environment. You need to look at having different build configurations (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.ASPX ) so that they don't apply regardless of what you deploy to.

Comment: I do have several config transforms and build configs. But I deploy the databases using the Nuget Console, typing Update-Database. And so I have several connectionstrings inside the Code-First project's (a Class Library) App.config. Maybe that is where I go wrong?

Comment: Its a while since I set it up, and it took a day or so to learn how to do it but now, when I deploy, I change the configuration to "Release", right-click on the solution and select "Publish". That opens a dialog with another "Publish" button. Click that 2nd button and it's done. Database migrations, website, settings the lot. I'm still using VS2010 BTW.I expect newer versions of Visual Studio make it even easier

Comment: Ok, we use publishing from TFS, which makes things somewhat more difficult. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: To sum up, this does not work for my scenario, as I want it to work by running Update-Database in the Nuget console. The configs are not being transformed when running it. Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896821/entity-framework-migrations-with-multiple-web-config-transforms

Answer (score 0):

Ogglas answer is in the right direction, but DB_NAME() returns a `nvarchar(128)`. Here's a 2-line version of their answer.

```cs
Sql(@"DECLARE @DB_NAME nvarchar(128) = DB_NAME();
EXEC ('ALTER DATABASE [' + @DB_NAME + '] SET FOO_BAR_BAZ ON')", true);
```

Replace `SET FOO_BAR_BAZ ON` with whatever you need.