# How to get the name of the database In Code First Migration

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm attempting to do a code first migration to turn on file streaming so that it doesn't have to be done manually.

I can of course configure file streaming at a database level (although I can't set the setting on the service...)

But I need to execute something like this

```
ALTER DATABASE DBNAME
```

ADD FILEGROUP FILESTREAMGroupName

CONTAINS FILESTREAM

So I need to get the name of the database that I'm working from.

Once I can get that then I can figure out the path to the main MDF by looking up the files and then set the path for the file stream group as my next command, but I just cannot figure out how to get the Database Name while in the DbMigration.

Ideas?

Comment: There is no access to the raw connection from within a DbMigration object. You'd have to read in the connection string from your web.config or app.config file, but you wouldn't be sure which connection the DbMigration would be executed on anyway.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access the database name inside Up in DbMigration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20118141/access-the-database-name-inside-up-in-dbmigration)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using MSSQL2012 you can use

```
ALTER DATABASE CURRENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Colin's comment about being a dupe is correct. The easiest way to do this is to use db_name() in your script.