# Is there an easy way to update-database from connection string in web.release.config?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

Using Code First .Net MVC, i use **update-database** to migrate my database from the latest model.  But my web.config file has my local db specified.  What i really want to use is the connection string from my web.release.config file.

Is there a way I can do this?  Am I missing something here?

I've been commenting/commenting-out different connection strings in the meanwhile.

One would think if my project is in "Release Mode," the Package manager console would know to look in the correct config.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Is your release configuration actually called "Release Mode" or are you using the default Release. How did you add the web.release.config to your project?

Comment: @Alioza Default release ... in the config.release ..xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" and transform the string

Comment: Make sure that in the Release the Debug configuration is not actually used. Open the solution Configuration Manager and switch the active configuration to Release. All projects should also have Release next to them.

Comment: Yeah, EF migrations won't read the transformed web.config. Options are to use  -ConnectionStringName or to run migrate.exe after the build. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173046/how-do-i-make-entity-framework-migrations-use-web-config-transforms